# urllib2 not fetching XML properly

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine

I have a python app in Google App Engine, and when I try to fetch an XML feed, nothing happens, except in the log console in the AppEngineLauncher, I get

```
WARNING  2013-03-21 23:37:39,482 urlfetch_stub.py:453] Stripped prohibited headers from URLFetch request: ['Host']
```

Here is my code:

```
class FindStops(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        bound=self.request.POST["bound"]
        line=self.request.POST["stop"]
        stops=urllib2.urlopen("http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=routeConfig&a=sf-muni&r=" + line)
        tree=ET.parse(stops)
        root=tree.getroot()
        title=list()
        for info in tree.findall('stop'):
            title.append(info.get('title'))

        for name in title:
            self.response.out.write(name)
```

And here is what the XML looks like:

```
<body copyright="All data copyright San Francisco Muni 2013.">
<route tag="F" title="F-Market & Wharves" color="555555" oppositeColor="ffffff"    latMin="37.7625199" latMax="37.8085899" lonMin="-122.43487" lonMax="-122.39345">
<stop tag="5184" title="Jones St & Beach St" lat="37.8072499" lon="-122.41737" stopId="15184"/>
<stop tag="3092" title="Beach St & Mason St" lat="37.80741" lon="-122.4141199" stopId="13092"/>
<stop tag="3095" title="Beach St & Stockton St" lat="37.8078399" lon="-122.41081" stopId="13095"/>
.
.
.
```

I'm pretty sure I"m parsing the XML correctly, but the self.response.out.write prints out nothing, so I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend to add:

```
logging.info( 'stops: ' + stops.read(100) )
```

right after using `urllib2.urlopen()` to see if you get the right response before blaming urllib2.